# How to convert a column values to column names in R and obtain a datased with one row for participant?

Tags: r, database, variables, columnsorting

I have a dataset (`questionnaire_demo`) with a lot of variables. I want to select some of them (`Participant.Private.ID, UTC.Date, Question.Key, Response`), filtering for some values (`gender`, `age`, `country`) of `Question.Key`.

I have selected something like this.

```
     Participant.Private.ID     UTC.Date      Question.Key   Response
1           xxxx              16/02/2022          gender        F
2           xxxx              16/02/2022            age         20
3           xxxx              16/02/2022          country       IT
```

My trouble is: I don't want to select `Question.Key` and `Response` in this form; I want to convert column values of col_1 as column names and column values of col_2 would be the column values associated with the column names.
So, I want to obtain a new disposition like:

```
     gender   age    country
1      F       20       IT
```

and include these new columns in the selection.
So I'll have something like, a row for participant:

```
   Partecipant.Private.ID    UTC.Date    gender   age   country
1          xxxx             16/02/2022     F       20      IT
```

I've tried something like this:

> ```
> library(reshape2)
> questionnaire_demo <- questionnaire_demo %>%
>   filter(Question.Key == "gender" | Question.Key == "age" | Question.Key == "country") %>%
> new_resp_demo <- dcast(questionnaire_demo, Response ~ Question.Key)
>   select(Participant.Private.ID, UTC.Date, new_resp_demo)
> ```

but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: It would be helpful to have a minimal data set to better understand its structure.

Comment: after filtering for `gender, age, country`, I obtain a dataset that looks like:
`   Partecipant.Private.ID    UTC.Date    Question.Key    Response
1          xxxx                      16/02/2022           gender            F 
2          xxxx                      16/02/2022           age                 20
3          xxxx                      16/02/2022           country            IT   
`

Comment: After filtering, `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Question.Key, values_from = Response)` should work.

Comment: I have no problem filtering the data, but I can't modify `Question.Key` and `Response` as I said in the question